# Google's idToken exp always set to 1970

Tags: node.js, google-signin, google-authentication

After receiving idToken from Google and verified, I noticed its `exp: 1623186214` is always set to 1970 which will always expire itself. For example `var when=new Date(1623186214);` resulting `Mon Jan 19 1970 10:53:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`.
How to address it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the `exp` is in seconds since midnight 01 January 1970 GMT.

So the correct way to check expiration is

```
var d=new Date('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'); // 1970-01-01 GMT
d.setUTCSeconds(1623259934); // the value of 'exp', note use UTC not setSeconds().
```

Now it's Wed Jun 09 2021 10:32:14 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), one hour after log in.

However, some better ways to validate it:

1. use Google's public endpoint
2. use Google's client library `google-auth-library`

Details on [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Answer (score 1):

JWT timestamp in seconds, but Javascript Date requiring milliseconds. But both JWT and Javascript Date constructor use the idea “since the epoch”. So just multiple exp by 1000.

```
new Date(exp * 1000)
```

￼